# Exporting a SQLite database to an XML file in Android

Tags: java, xml, android, sqlite

I know this is possible but I'm not really sure where to start. Has anyone been able to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DataXmlExporter` class described in this article will export a SQL lite DB to an XML file.

http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7749

The full example is available in this SVN repo. The [`ManageData`](http://totsp.com/svn/repo/AndroidExamples/trunk/src/com/totsp/androidexamples/ManageData.java) class invokes the export.

http://totsp.com/svn/repo/AndroidExamples/trunk/

You will need to create an application class that exposes the DB and referenced as the application name in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Then use that DB as the argument to the `DataXmlExporter` constructor.

Here's the application class I use. You should already have a class (probably not named `DatabaseHelper`) that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`

```
package com.billybobbain.android.someapp;
import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

   public static final String APP_NAME = "SomeApp";  

   private DatabaseHelper dataHelper;   

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      Log.d(APP_NAME, "APPLICATION onCreate");
      this.dataHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);      
   }

   @Override
   public void onTerminate() {
      Log.d(APP_NAME, "APPLICATION onTerminate");      
      super.onTerminate();      
   }

   public DatabaseHelper getDataHelper() {
      return this.dataHelper;
   }

   public void setDataHelper(DatabaseHelper dataHelper) {
      this.dataHelper = dataHelper;
   }
}
```

Comment: How would one go about calling this class?

Comment: Thanks for the added detail Wayne. I do have another question, If I wanted to export the database when a user presses a button, for example, "Send Database", would I map the button to start an intent for the MyApplication class or the XMLExport class?.

Comment: That android example linked above does exactly what you want. You should be able to just add that code to your application, change the filenames a bit, add the intent to the manifest & be good to go. It has a backup DB button & an export to XML button on the activity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Wayne. I guess my question is, How much of the example above would I need to add to my existing code if I just wanted to include the export XML part. To my understanding I would need the above "MyApplication" class, but how would I start this in an intent as it does not extend Activity?. 

I am a bit confused as to which sections I would need.

Thanks.

Comment: @BillyBobBain Could you please check the links above? They can't open right now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Billy Bob Bain:Hello , can you ccheck the links please because they don't work and I want to implement the code?Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the source code here [exporting-a-sqlite-database-to-an-xml-file-in-android](http://mgmblog.com/2009/02/06/export-an-android-sqlite-db-to-an-xml-file-on-the-sd-card/)

The only change I had to make (to stop a few Eclipse warnings) was to close a cursor in the exportData( ) method. To make the code more portable, I also passed the XML file and location as an argument rather then as a declared final field.

The code writes the XML file to the SD card. Now, @mmaitlen who listed the source code on his blog doesn't add in any features to test for the existence of an external storage unit. So that's left for you to do.

However, you can embed some simple code to test for the existence of a writeable memory card with the following snippet (untested):

```
    sdOkToWrite = false;
    String sdTest = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (sdTest.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        sdOkToWrite = true;
    } else {
    // Here's where you can code what to do without the external storage
    }
```

Testing for the external storage is useful if you have large files to create that may exceed internal capacity.

Answer (score 1):

I found this very helpful:

http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1788273/

Using it the following way to export it to the sd card:

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path = sd + "/" + DB_NAME + ".xml";

DatabaseDump databaseDump = new DatabaseDump(mySQLiteOpenHelperObject.getReadableDatabase(), path);
databaseDump.exportData();
```

Of course don't forget:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```