# Export SQLite database into XML file

Tags: android, xml, android-sqlite

How can I export data from database and store it in an `XML` file?

My database schema looks like this:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "instruments.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "instrument_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "LOCATION";
public static final String COL_4 = "INFORMATION";
public static final String COL_5 = "PHOTO";
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585934/exporting-a-sqlite-database-to-an-xml-file-in-android)

Comment: I have check that one but none of the link are working in verified answer of that question and rest are literally not to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181294/how-to-create-xml-file-in-android) post and [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) tutorial to get you started. You will need to use `XmlSerializer` to create the XML file. This [post](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer.html) should also help you out.